# Gekko is taking too long to solve very complex MINLP problem

Tags: optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve a MINLP model where I have people that have different schedules and can perform different tasks, and there is a maximum of tasks that each can perform at each schedule, according to their available time.

So as indexes I have, i for people, z for schedule, j for task and a for the order of the task.

The model is something like this:

[image]

Every K is a cost of something, in blue the cost of the tasking taking more than planned, in orange the cost of the task taking less than planned, in yellow the cost of the delay of next tasks and in purple the cost of not occupying all the people available time.
TC (decision variable) is the duration of the task which must be the same for each people for each task and C (decision variable) is the decision of if the task is going to be performed or not in that specific order since there are schedules where they can perform more than one task.

My restrictions are something like:

[image]

Something like this (very small part of the data) it solves in 10 minutes:

[image]

But something like this (more data, and we whould need way more than this example) maxed out 140 minutes of time limite that I defined:

[image]

I am not sure if I am defining something wrong in my problem (either mathematically or conceptually) or if there is something else that I can do to improve performance. If there is more information that you think is required for being able to help, please let me know.

I have tried to simplify the model/problem and use some Gekko options.

Thank you.

## UPDATE

After trying some suggestions, I have come to this.
Currently I have the following:

```py
tc_var = {}
for index in index_f_a:
    tc_var[index] = m.Var(value=25, name='tc_var_{}'.format(index), lb=15, ub=45, integer=False)

s_var = {}
for index in index_f_h:
     s_var[index] = m.Var()

for i, z in index_f_h:
    m.Equation(tmd[(i, z)]*0.8 + s_var[(i, z)] == np.sum([index_a_v[(i, z)][-1][1]*tc_var[(i, j)] for j in list(set([x[0] for x in index_a_v[(i, z)]]))]) )
    m.Equation(s_var[(i, z)] >= 0)

def k1(i, z, j, a):
    a_dif = tce[(i, z, j, a)] - tc_var[(i, j)].VALUE
    return a_dif if a_dif > 0 else 0

def k2(i, z, j, a):
    a_dif = tc_var[(i, j)].VALUE - tce[(i, z, j, a)]
    return a_dif if a_dif > 0 else 0

def k3(i, z, j, a):
    a_dif = np.sum([tce[(i, z, j, a2)] for a2 in index_f_h_a_v1[i, z, j]]) - (a-1)*tc_var[(i, j)].VALUE 
    return a_dif if a_dif > 0 else 0

def k4(i, z):
    a_dif = tmd[(i, z)] - np.sum([index_a_v[(i, z)][-1][1]*tc_var[(i, j)].VALUE for j in list(set([x[0] for x in index_a_v[(i, z)]]))])
    return a_dif if a_dif > 0 else 0


m.Minimize(m.sum([k1(i, z, j, a)*KCA 
              + k2(i, z, j, a)*KCI 
              + k3(i, z, j, a)*KME 
              for i, z, j, a in index_f_h_a_v])
       + m.sum([k4(i, z) for i, z in index_f_h]) * KI 
            )

m.options.MAX_TIME=600 
m.options.MAX_ITER=5000
m.options.REDUCE=3

m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',
                'minlp_branch_method 1',
                'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500']
```

## Final Correction

Check question: [Access decision variable value in function outside objective function Gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753747/access-decision-variable-value-in-function-outside-objective-function-gekko)

Comment: This is a really broad question, without much supporting detail.  Most successful questions here are focused on a specific coding issue.  You would likely need somebody to look at (a) your math model (more than what you have posted), (b) your implementation, and (c) your solver selections.  That could be a big ask!  That said, I see in the limited info you provided that you are formulating this scheduling problem with a `max()` function, which means you are making a non-linear mixed integer formulation, which is usually a *really problematic* approach to a scheduling problem.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the help. I did not know what information to share since I do not know where the problem might be, I understand that this might make it hard to help, however i hoped it was enough to get some suggestions of what to look for, or where to look. Regarding the use of max() is because I only want to consider the costs if the difference between the effective time and planned is positive... Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: You really need to pursue a linear formulation if the problem is large for a variety of reasons.  As stated, without digging in on all of the model to get a sense of how time is handled, other variables, etc. it is difficult to advise.  To alleviate the `max()` one strategy is to introduce a "helper" non-negative variable, indexed by task (?) probably that is constrained to be larger than all the things you want to consider, then multiply that by the penalty.  You also need to remove the multiplication of variables `C` and `TC`

Comment: AirSquid has a good suggestion. Another substitute for `m.max3()`, is to introduce a slack variable that become non-zero when the cost difference is negative such as `cost=f(x)+s` with `cost>=0`, `s>=0`, and `m.Minimize(1e-5*s)`. This adds a slight penalty on `s` that can be tuned to be insignificant compared to other objectives.

Comment: I have been trying your suggestions, thank you both, but now I have come to a different problem. It does not find a solution when I increase the size of the problem... I think it might have been related with the fact that I am getting negative DOF and I tried the slack variables but I did not work. I have edited my question to add what I have now. Can you please check it?

Comment: I had an error in the formulation. In here, index_a_v[(i, z)][-1][1]*tc_var[(i, j)].VALUE i should be doing (index_a_v[(i, z)][-1][1]+1)*tc_var[(i, j)].VALUE. It appears the problem is now feasible. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Using `.value` in the objective only uses the initial value. Please create a new question with a simplified version that demonstrates the issue if you'd like more specific help with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Try solving as an NLP problem first without the mixed integer variables. This can be configured by using the IPOPT solver with `m.options.SOLVER=3` or with the APOPT solver `m.options.SOLVER=1` and the solver option `m.solver_options = ['minlp_as_nlp 1']`. [Additional details on solver options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) are in the documentation. Use the NLP solution as an initial guess for the MINLP solution.

```py
# initialize with NLP solver
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve()

# calculate MINLP solution
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()
```

2. The number of variables can generally be reduced with `m.Intermediate()` or by using a presolve with `m.options.REDUCE=3`. This eliminates some of the implicit variables. Solving `50844` binary variables in a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) problem can take a while.
3. Use `sum()` instead of `m.sum()` for faster model compile times. As long as the symbolic equation length limit of 15,000 is not exceeded it can improve the model performance with the regular Python `sum()` function.
4. If the model can be reduced to a MILP problem, try other solvers such as Gurobi, CPLEX, or FICO Xpress. They are commercial solvers that generally do better with linear programming problems than using a nonlinear solver.
5. There are [additional ways to solve scheduling problems](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ScheduleOptimization) that can generate an initial guess for the MINLP solver.
6. Try depth-first search to generate `m.solver_options = ['minlp_branch_method 1']` to quickly generate a feasible solution and start eliminating branches from the branch-and-bound method. Adding `minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500` terminates after 500 iterations once an integer (feasible) solution is located.

```py
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1.0e-2',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500']
```

If you can share a simplified version of your model that demonstrates the issue, the community can give more specific suggestions.